# Is distance() method written as it should

Tags: java, oop

regarding the following code, can I make it better for `distance()` method?
It feels like it's not completely OOP with this method.. how can I change code to be better OOD for this one ?

Thanks !!

```
public class Line extends Shape {

    private Point lineP1; 
    private Point lineP2;

    public Line(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Color myColor) {
        super(x1, x2, y1, y2, myColor);

        lineP1 = new Point(this.getX1(),this.getY1());
        lineP2 = new Point(this.getX2(),this.getY2());
    }



    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {      
        g.drawLine(this.getX1(), this.getY1(), this.getX2(), this.getY2()); 
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Point p) {
        if((this.distance(lineP1, p)+this.distance(lineP2, p)) == this.distance(lineP1, lineP2))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    /**@return distance between two given points
     * This method return the distance between two given points*/
    private double distance(Point p1,Point p2 ){
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow((p1.getX()-p2.getX()), 2) + Math.pow((p1.getY()-p2.getY()), 2));
    }

}//class Line
```

Comment: This isn't clear.  What does "completely OOP" mean?

Comment: rename to `oop_distance` should do it

Comment: As a side note: `a * a` is usually better than `Math.pow(a, 2)`. Further more as you don't need to calculate actual distances than you can remove `Math.sqrt()` call as well

Comment: @GermannArlington:  why ?
OliverCharlesworth: I think that if a method isn't static, it should be work with the object, means it's an object ability ?

Comment: Beside minor points (like the one about Math.pow) that's as OOP as you can get, unless you are aiming for a specific design pattern (or something else)

Comment: @st2rseeker, the distance method gets 2 objects who aren't related to the Line object and except for a simple calc. it might be expected to be a static method, isn't it ?

Comment: BTW: There is a much better ways of checking, if a point is on a line: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form

Comment: @fabian: but how do u implement it by code ?

Comment: @Batman Point (pun intended) - this belong to the Point class (something like - p1.distance(p2)). Regarding the statics - no need adding them just for the heck of it, IMHO (statics will complicated future changes you may want to do).

Comment: @st2rseeker so you would advice not to change the 'distance' method I wrote ?

Comment: Calculating the [scalar product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_product) is simple enough; Rotating a 2D vector by 90° means you have to swap coordinates and multiply one of them with `-1`. The point is: Using the Hesse normal form you can easily calculate the distance to a line with 2 multiplications and 1 addition + 1 substraction (assuming you prepared the normal). (you have to do that twice, if you want to ensure the point is between the end points of the line). Also it allows you to allow small errors in a much better way. (using `double`s you likely don't get exact values)

Comment: @fabian can you show a code example for that ?

Comment: If you can't move it to Point, yeah - it's fine. Regarding the calculation - @fabian, that's an interesting method; than you for sharing. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your distance method seems to be ok (but it would be more performant, if you saved the differences in variables and used the `*` operator to multiply those values with themselfs instear of using `Math.pow`).

However, since floating point calculations tend to return inexact results, I don't recomend using the sum of the distances between the end node and the point to test as criterium.

But there's another good way determining, if a point is near a line or not: using the [hesse normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form). It works like this:

Let `P1` and `P2` be vectors corresponing to the end points. `*` denotes the scalar multiplication and `||` the length of a vector:

```
D = (P2 - P1) / |P2 - P1|;
```

Let `N` be the vector `D` with coordinates swaped and the new x coordinate multiplied with `-1` (i.e. a vector ortogonal to D).

Then the distance of a point `H` to the line can be determined like this

```
| N * H - N * P1 |
```

Also if `H` is between `P1` and `P2` can be checked like this (assuming without loss of generality `D * P1 < D * P2`):

```
D * P1 <= D * H <= D * P2
```

Using scalar products has the additional benefit, that calculating a scalar product only takes 2 multiplication and 1 addition in a 2D space.

This is how you could do this in java code

```
// components of normal vector
private double normalX;
private double normalY;

// components of direction vector
private double directionX;
private double directionY;

// the value of (N * P) for all points P on the line
private double normalScalarProduct;

// the range allowed for (D * P) for points on the line
private double minDirectionScalarProduct;
private double maxDirectionScalarProduct;

// error ranges; adjust as appropriate
private static final double directionAllowedError = 0.1;
private static final double normalAllowedError = 0.1;

public Line(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2, Color myColor) {
    ...
    double dx = x2 - x1;
    double dy = y2 - y1;
    double length = distance(dx, dy);
    if (length == 0) {
        // choose arbitrary direction, if length == 0
        length = 1;
        dx = 1;
    }

    // normalize direction
    dx /= length;
    dy /= length;

    // set D and N values
    this.directionX = dx;
    this.directionY = dy;
    this.normalX = -dy;
    this.normalY = dx;

    double prod1 = scalarProduct(directionX, directionY, x1, y1);
    double prod2 = scalarProduct(directionX, directionY, x2, y2);

    if (prod1 < prod2) {
        minDirectionScalarProduct = prod1 - directionAllowedError;
        maxDirectionScalarProduct = prod2 + directionAllowedError;
    } else {
        minDirectionScalarProduct = prod2 - directionAllowedError;
        maxDirectionScalarProduct = prod1 + directionAllowedError;
    }

    normalScalarProduct = scalarProduct(x1, y1, normalX, normalY);
}

private static double scalarProduct(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2) {
    return x1*x2 + y1*y2;
}

public boolean contains(Point p) {
    if (Math.abs(scalarProduct(p.getX(), p.getX(), normalX, normalY) - normalScalarProduct) <= normalAllowedError) {
        // close enough to the line -> check, if between end points
        double d = scalarProduct(p.getX(), p.getX(), directionX, directionY);
        return minDirectionScalarProduct <= d && d <= maxDirectionScalarProduct;
    }
    return false;
}

private double distance(double dx, double dy) {
    return Math.sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
}
```